# In log file many different date format

Tags: windows, date, server, windows-7-x64

I write a script to replace all date formats into a similar format in the file. I need to write a window script to find and replace date formates.

It is found only if the date is a separate word but if the date in the long word, can't find.
How I can replace it? in another format

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO ON
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,* delims=/-" %%i in ('type "log.old"') do (
set "year=%%i"
set "month=%%j"
set "day=%%k"
    findstr /N /O [1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/ ie8.log
ECHO i = %%i
ECHO j = %%j    
ECHO k = %%k
echo %%k/%%j/%%i
)>>"new.log"
```